# SQL INSERT: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I can't figure out even after reading other questions that have a similar title, why this isn't working.  I get an error on the final INSERT statement.

```
WITH qryRecordsNotYetCompleted AS
(
    SELECT  FormNbr,
            UserAssigned,
            DateAssignedToAnalyst,
            AssignmentStatus,
            DateImportedFromSQL,
            DateCompletedbyBAA,
            DateSentToClaimsToolbar
    FROM PENDS_BAA_MASTER WHERE ISNULL(DateCompletedbyBAA,'')=''
)
--/**********************************************************************************************

--2) For all those records, save any ASSIGNMENT information AND original DateImportedFromSQL value
SELECT qryRecordsNotYetCompleted.* INTO #TempPends FROM qryRecordsNotYetCompleted

--/**********************************************************************************************

--2b:
INSERT PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp
SELECT * FROM #TempPends
```

I checked, and PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp definitely has columns UserAssigned, DateAssignedToAnalyst, AssignmentStatus, DateImportedFromSQL, DateCompletedByBAA, DateSentToClaimsToolbar.  And they are the exact same column types as PENDS_BAA_MASTER, which, due to the flow of my statements, should carry through.

Comment: Does `PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp` have any **other** columns besides those you specified? And does the column order match?

Comment: Does `PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp` have more columns than your CTE?

Comment: Why do you need #TempPends at all? Seems you could do this in a single insert statement instead of so many copies.

Comment: might be a dumb question, but dont you need an INTO between INSERT and PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp

Comment: Mureinik, yes, it has a bunch of other columns.  But I thought that because I was NOT specifying Columns(, , , ) Values (, , , ), but rather just inserting a Select *, then that was OK.

Doesn't SQL Server just insert Nulls for the rest?

Comment: @Sean:  I don't disagree with you at all.  I'm very new to T-SQL and at first, it's easier to learn and test the code by using CTEs and a few temp tables.  Eventually I will combine and make it more efficient.  For the moment I need to break it apart a little more as a crutch so that visually I cna understand it better.

Comment: @ItalianStallion - No

Comment: You mention all of the columns exist in PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp except for FormNbr.

Comment: Sorry Sean, that was a typo.  ALL of the ones from qryRecordsNotYetCompleted (7 of them) do exist also in PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as a single insert statement. Like this. You have FormNbr in your original query but didn't mention it in the target table.

```
INSERT PENDS_BAA_MASTER_Temp
(
    UserAssigned
    , DateAssignedToAnalyst
    , AssignmentStatus
    , DateImportedFromSQL
    , DateCompletedbyBAA
    , DateSentToClaimsToolbar
)
SELECT UserAssigned
    , DateAssignedToAnalyst
    , AssignmentStatus
    , DateImportedFromSQL
    , DateCompletedbyBAA
    , DateSentToClaimsToolbar
FROM PENDS_BAA_MASTER
```